# Storybook only loading Emotion Styling first load

Tags: css, typescript, material-ui, storybook

I'm using the `styled` api from `emotion` to create a styled button.

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: ${theme.palette.grey['800']};
  width: 50;
  height: 50;
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${theme.palette.grey['600']};
  }
  & .MuiButton-label {
    color: #fff;
  }
`;
```

However, when I expose this in Storybook, I only see the styling appear on the first component render

[image: Styled Button]

And when I change components the styling disappears (from computed properties and visual representation)

[image: unstyled button]

The styling reappears when I reload the actual page... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I figured out the answer :P... There is [a note from MaterialUI](https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/) about injection priority, so I made a custom decorator

```
export const withInjection = (story) => (
  <StylesProvider injectFirst>
    { story() }
  </StylesProvider>
)
```

and added to my `preview.ts`

```
// style priority injection
addDecorator(withInjection);
```

and now it's working consistently :)